Calculate a running percentage to increase the total each month to get end with 1000
I'm attempting to calculate the percentage increase needed month over month, with the first month starting at 20, to end the year with 1000.
I envision the solution to be something like last-month(20)*8.2; that's way off and, I'm sure there is a far better solution.
The concept I'm trying to achieve is to start with "20" in the first month and increase it by a percentage (that I need to find) each month to total all 12 months to 1000.

I think what you want is the sum of a geometric series, which is given by the formula:
S = a * (1 - r^n) / (1 - r)

In your case,
S = 1000
n = 12
a = 20
r = we need to solve for

Using Excel, I think the simplest solution would be to set r as its own cell and either (1) use Excel's Solver tool to find r, or (2) using trial and error, plug values into the r cell until you reach a solution that is close enough. The solution I arrive at is approximately 123.719%.

This is extremely helpful. Thank you. However, my question may have been too vague. I was hoping to find a way to make the rate more of a cascading rate that increases each month incrementally so that the sum of the range equals 1000.
